# In Java, how to iterate on the constants of an interface?

Tags: java

in an interface, I store constants in this way (I'd like to know what you think of this practice). This is just a dummy example.

```
interface HttpConstants {
    /** 2XX: generally "OK" */
    public static final int HTTP_OK = 200;
    public static final int HTTP_CREATED = 201;
    public static final int HTTP_ACCEPTED = 202;
    public static final int HTTP_NOT_AUTHORITATIVE = 203;
    public static final int HTTP_NO_CONTENT = 204;
    public static final int HTTP_RESET = 205;
    public static final int HTTP_PARTIAL = 206;

        ...
}
```

Is there a way I can iterate over all constants declared in this interface ?

Comment: Opinion: enums _do_ provide a lot of benefits in modern code, highly recommended. BUT not in all cases. Strings are used a lot analogue to "identifier" (e.g. attribute names, properties keys, JSF view IDs, JPA named query names and query placeholders, security roles, ...). Problem: string literals are _very_ easy to mistype, and have no compile time checking. I prefer to declare all such strings as constants, usually in an enum. HOWEVER, when using them as **annotation parameters**, enums aren't allowed and one still has to fall back on `public static final String`s similar to your code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using reflection:

```
Field[] interfaceFields=HttpConstants.class.getFields();
for(Field f:interfaceFields) {
   //do something
}
```

But anyway, if you can redesign your class, I would recomend you to handle a static enum constants construction. So, suposing your class will contain always an int value for every constant:

```
enum HttpConstants {

    HTTP_OK(200), HTTP_CREATED(201), HTTP_ACCEPTED(202),
    HTTP_NOT_AUTHORITATIVE(203),HTTP_NO_CONTENT(204), 
    HTTP_RESET(205), HTTP_PARTIAL(206) /* ... */;

    private int value;

    HttpConstants(int aValue) {
        value=aValue;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then, to loop on it:

```
    for(HttpConstants val: HttpConstants.values()) {
        int value=val.getValue();
            //...
    }
```

Thus, avoiding the access to the reflection API.

Answer (score 6):

I would create these constants as an enumeration. Enums in Java can have their own fields and methods, which very convenient for your case. So I would do this the following way:

```
enum HttpConstant {
    HTTP_OK(200),
    HTTP_CREATED(201),
    HTTP_ACCEPTED(202),
    HTTP_NOT_AUTHORITATIVE(203),
    HTTP_NO_CONTENT(204),
    HTTP_RESET(205),
    HTTP_PARTIAL(206);

    private final int id;

    HttpConstant(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Now the iteration is easy:

```
for (HttpConstant constant : HttpConstant.values()) {
    //Do something with the constant
}
```

This way it is also easy to add associate some new values with the constants, you just have to add new fields.

Right now you may use reflection:

```
Field[] interfaceFields = HttpConstants.class.getFields();
for (Field field : interfaceFields) {
    int constant = field.getInt(null);
    //Do something with the field
}
```

However, it is better to use the approach with enums because with reflection coding errors result in runtime exceptions instead of compile-time errors.

Answer (score 4):

```
for(Field f : HttpConstants.class.getFields()){
       int constant = f.getInt(null);
}
```

Comment: btw those constants are defined in java.net.HttpURLConnection

Answer (score 3):

```
public enum HttpConstant {
    /** 2XX: generally "OK" */
    HTTP_OK(200).
    HTTP_CREATED(201),
    HTTP_ACCEPTED(202),
    HTTP_NOT_AUTHORITATIVE(203),
    HTTP_NO_CONTENT(204),
    HTTP_RESET(205),
    HTTP_PARTIAL(206);

    private int code;
    private HttpConstant(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

with `HttpConstant.values()`.

Answer (score 2):

Well usually when i have something like that i make a Map in the interface that has the keys - constant names with values constant - values.

And that's how i can iterate over them.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to know what you think of this practice

Consider using an `enum` instead of an interface with constants.

```
enum HttpResultCode {
    HTTP_OK(200),
    HTTP_CREATED(201),
    HTTP_ACCEPTED(202),
    HTTP_NOT_AUTHORITATIVE(203),
    HTTP_NO_CONTENT(204),
    HTTP_RESET(205),
    HTTP_PARTIAL(206);

    private final int code;

    private HttpResultCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getCode(int code) {
        return code;
    }

    public static HttpResultCode forCode(int code) {
        for (HttpResultCode e : HttpResultCode.values()) {
            if (e.code == code) {
                return e;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid code: " + code);
    }
}
```